# SharePoint workflow to XAML?

Tags: sharepoint, xaml, workflow

I have one workflow deployed on SharePoint server.
Now can I reverse engineer that and create (workflow)XAML out of it?
if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2007 does not support reuse of XAML/SharePoint Designer Workflows. I have not see people succeeded doing so, as it is designed in such a way that WF is pinned to a specific list or Doc Lib. But same process is supported in [SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335710.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Kusek, But i m using VS-Studio 2008 to develop workflow. i found workaround i dont is it correct or not. I found associated WorkFlow with list then by using refrection i have created instance of WorkFlow.